# Using a 120V soldering iron with 240V

Tags: voltage, ac, soldering

I have a [cheap, 40W 120V soldering iron](https://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/aven-tools/17521/243-1267-ND/5252794) with no temperature adjustment. Given the internal circuitry seems pretty simple would it generally be safe to run it on 240V?

Comment: Define "pretty simple"

Comment: I can't put an answer down because the question was closed, but I would say give it a try; these soldering guns are usually very underpowered. They are just a transformer. Hold the trigger down for less time than normal.

Answer (score 6):

A big NO. What would you expect a 120V lamp to do if you powered it from 240V!  The results could be similar.

A simple soldering iron is just a resistor - if you put twice the voltage into it it will produce 4 times the heat - rather than heating to 700°F it could get to 1000° or more.  It could cause a fire, the insulation could break down and cause electrocution danger.

You could run it from a step down transformer - one capable of powering it should no be expensive but neither would a 240v soldering iron.

Comment: Ah, forgot about V squared.. It wouldn't have a thermal switch that would effectively let it run at a lower duty cycle? Or is the resistor simply matched to the voltage to give the correct temperature?

Comment: I wouldn't count on that. These are generally a resistive element attached to mains. (If it had any active circuitry it would probably be rated for 110~240V.)

Comment: These usually are PTC heaters, meaning they are self-controlling. It doesn't work for a completely out-of-range operation of course.

Comment: @Janka - It is very uncommon to use PTC heaters in a soldering iron - I have never heard of one. Simple soldering irons are plain resistive heaters.  More sophisticated non-electronic ones usually use a thermostatic switch based on the curie point of a magnet in the tip.

Comment: You could also use a simple lamp dimmer to reduce the power. The soldering iron doesn't care about the waveform -- just the average power.